# Phonegap/Cordova, register device orientation when camera is active

Tags: cordova, rotation, accelerometer, image

In my Phonegap/Cordova app I'm uploading a picture (taken by the camera) to a webserver. At the webserver I'm doing some modification for creating a smaller picture instead of the 8megapixel iPhone picture.

When I upload a picture taken in portrait modus my server thinks it was shot in landscape modus, so the picture is rotated 90°. When I upload a landscape picture everything is fine.

I don't support landscape modus in my app. How could I handle this? Is there an option in Phonegap/Cordova that automatically could check if a picture was shot in landscape/portrait modus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, that was an easy one. just add "correctOrientation: true," to the options at "navigator.camera.getPicture" and now everything works fine :) (just by the way, this is nowhere mentioned at the phonegap "documentation"...)

Comment: It is now: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html - it doesn't seem to work for android among others though